Apple Vision Pro Hand Tracking Palm towards face or not
I'm trying to create a function for the Apple Vision Pro that determines whether my palm is facing me (facing the device) or not. Here's a high-level overview of the problem:

Define a Forward Vector for the Palm
I created a forward vector for the palm by referencing its forward direction (Z-axis in its transformation matrix). This gives me the direction the palm is facing.

Get the Forward Vector for the Head
I did the same for the head, extracting its forward direction to understand where it's facing.

Perform a Dot Product
I then used the dot product between the palm's forward vector and the head's forward vector. If the dot product is greater than 0, the palm is generally facing the head. By adjusting the threshold (e.g., 0.2), I could fine-tune how directly the palm needs to face the head for it to count as "facing."


I normalized both vectors before calculating the dot product to ensure they were unit vectors.
Unfortunately, I'm not getting the outcome I expected.
Here is my solution in swift:
func isPalmFacingDevice(palmPos: simd_float4x4, facePos: simd_float4x4) -> Bool {
        // Extract positions from the 4x4 matrices
        let palmPos3x3 = simd_make_float3(palmPos.columns.3.x,
                                          palmPos.columns.3.y,
                                          palmPos.columns.3.z)

        let headPos3x3 = simd_make_float3(facePos.columns.3.x,
                                          facePos.columns.3.y,
                                          facePos.columns.3.z)

        // Calculate forward directions from the 4x4 matrices
        // In a 4x4 matrix, the forward direction is typically in the negative Z-axis (third column)
        let palmForwardDirection = simd_make_float3(palmPos.columns.2.x,
                                                    palmPos.columns.2.y,
                                                    palmPos.columns.2.z)

        let headForwardDirection = simd_make_float3(facePos.columns.2.x,
                                                    facePos.columns.2.y,
                                                    facePos.columns.2.z)

        // Normalize both direction vectors to make them unit vectors
        let normalizedPalmDirection = simd_normalize(palmForwardDirection)
        let normalizedHeadDirection = simd_normalize(headForwardDirection)

        // Perform the dot product between the normalized forward directions
        let dotProduct = simd_dot(normalizedPalmDirection, normalizedHeadDirection)

        // If the dot product is close to 1, the palm is facing the head (in the same direction)
        print("Dot Product: \(dotProduct)")

        return dotProduct > 0
    }

Further, here is how I am extracting the coordinates of the palm and head:
for await anchorUpdate in handTracking.anchorUpdates {
                    let anchor = anchorUpdate.anchor
                    
                    switch anchor.chirality {
                    case .left:
                        if let handSkeleton = anchor.handSkeleton {
                            let palmPos = handSkeleton.joint(.middleFingerKnuckle).anchorFromJointTransform
                            let headPos = worldTracking.queryDeviceAnchor(atTimestamp: CACurrentMediaTime())
                            
                            if let headPos = await fetchHeadPositionWithRetry() {
                                print("Palm is facing my face: \(isPalmFacingDevice(palmPos: palmPos, facePos: headPos))")
                                print(headPos)
                            } else {
                                print("Failed to fetch head position.")
                            }
                            
                            
                        }


My issue is that I'm basically only getting a dot product of ~0.9 as shown in these logs:
Dot Product: 0.9786667
Palm is facing my face: true

